# Find or Create with Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have recently started working with [Laravel](http://laravel.com) and [Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent), and was wondering about the lack of a find or create option for models. You could always write, for example:

```
$user = User::find($id);
if (!$user) {
    $user = new User;
}
```

However, is there not a better way to find or create? It seems trivial in the example, but for more complex situations it would be really helpfully to either get an existing record and update it or create a new one.

Comment: I am not an Eloquent expert, however even if there is no such method, most probably you can define it in an abstract class or trait that all of your models extend / make use of.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Below is the original accepted answer for: [Laravel-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-4)

There is already a method `findOrFail` available in `Laravel` and when this method is used it throws `ModelNotFoundException` on fail but in your case you can do it by creating a method in your model, for example, if you have a `User` model then you just put this function in the model

```
// Put this in any model and use
// Modelname::findOrCreate($id);
public static function findOrCreate($id)
{
    $obj = static::find($id);
    return $obj ?: new static;
}
```

From your controller, you can use

```
$user =  User::findOrCreate(5);
$user->first_name = 'John';
$user->last_name = 'Doe';
$user->save();
```

If a user with `id` of `5` exists, then it'll be updated, otherwise a new user will be created but the `id` will be `last_user_id + 1` (auto incremented).

This is another way to do the same thing:

```
public function scopeFindOrCreate($query, $id)
{
    $obj = $query->find($id);
    return $obj ?: new static;
}
```

Instead of creating a static method, you can use a `scope` in the Model, so the method in the `Model` will be `scopeMethodName` and call `Model::methodName()`, same as you did in the static method, for example

```
$user =  User::findOrCreate(5);
```

### Update:

The `firstOrCreate` is available in `Laravel 5x`, the answer is too old and it was given for `Laravel-4.0` in `2013`.

In Laravel 5.3, the `firstOrCreate` method has the following declaration:

```
public function firstOrCreate(array $attributes, array $values = [])
```

Which means you can use it like this:

```
User::firstOrCreate(['email' => $email], ['name' => $name]);
```

User's existence will be only checked via email, but when created, the new record will save both email and name.

[API Docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_firstOrCreate)

Comment: `findOrCreate` doesn't exist in Laravel 5x, as you cannot create something using only the ID. I think what you are referring to is `findOrNew`.

Comment: Right @SteveEdson but it's `firstOrCreate` :-)

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that if the object was created by `firstOrCreate` then it has not yet been persisted to the database. You will need to call save manually to persist it.

Comment: @Adam, Actually `firstOrNew` does that (what you mentioned here) but `firstOrCreate` persists it. [Check here.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#other-creation-methods)

Comment: @TheAlpha, may I ask you to have a look at a Laravel  join query related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52149031/laravel-join-query-with-conditions ?

Answer (score 34):

Alternatively, in this case you can also use Laravel's function and search for id as an attribute, i.e.

```
$user = User::firstOrCreate(['id' => $id]);
```

Comment: Docs for 4: http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_firstOrCreate

Comment: Docs for 5: http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_firstOrCreate

Answer (score 14):

In Laravel 5:
There are two methods you may use to create models by mass assigning attributes: `firstOrCreate` and `firstOrNew`. 
The `firstOrCreate` method will attempt to locate a database record using the given column / value pairs. If the model can not be found in the database, a record will be **inserted** with the given attributes.
The `firstOrNew` method, like `firstOrCreate` will attempt to locate a record in the database matching the given attributes. However, if a model is not found, a **new model instance will be returned**. Note that the model returned by `firstOrNew` has not yet been persisted to the database. You will need to call save manually to persist it:

```
// Retrieve the flight by the attributes, or create it if it doesn't exist...
$flight = App\Flight::firstOrCreate(['name' => 'Flight 10']);

// Retrieve the flight by the attributes, or instantiate a new instance...
$flight = App\Flight::firstOrNew(['name' => 'Flight 10']);
```

Answer (score 13):

Find or New based on primary key **id**

```
$user = User::findOrNew($id); // if exist then update else insert
$user->name= $data['full_name'];
$user->save();
```

First or New based on non-primary key **single filed**

```
// get the record where field_name=value else insert new record
$user = User::firstOrNew(['field_name'=>'value']); 
$user->name= $data['full_name'];
$user->save();
```

First or New based on non-primary key **multiple filed**

```
// get the record where field_name1=value1 and field_name2=value2, else insert new record
$user = User::firstOrNew(['field_name1'=>'value1','field_name2'=>'value2']);
$user->name= $data['full_name'];
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 11):

Laravel 4 models have a built-in [`findOrNew`](http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_findOrNew) method that does what you need:

```
$user = User::findOrNew($id);
```

Comment: note find or new instantiates an object but you still need to use save() function

Answer (score 3):

You can use firstOrCreate (It's working with Laravel 4.2)

```
$bucketUser = BucketUser::firstOrCreate([
    'bucket_id' => '1',
    'user_id'   => '2',
]);
```

returns found instance or new instance.