# call custom model's method from controller in laravel4

Tags: php, function, model, controller, laravel

I am trying to call a custom method in my `Email` model from my `SessionsController`. This is my model

```
<?php

class Email extends Eloquent {
    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array();

    public function sendMail($type,$data)
    {
        echo "yes";
    }
}
```

From my `SessionsController` I wanna call `sendMail` method. How am I supposed to call it?

Answer (score 10):

You can do it either, using

```
class Email extends Eloquent {
    public static function sendMail($type, $data)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

And call from controller

```
Email::sendMail('someType', $dataArray);
```

Or, you can use `Scope` (instead of `static`)

```
class Email extends Eloquent {
    public function scopeSendMail($query, $type, $data)
    {
        // You can use $query here
        // i.e. $query->find(1);
    }
}
```

And call it from controller

```
Email::sendMail('someType', $dataArray);
```

Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309033/find-or-create-with-eloquent/20309494#20309494).

Comment: thank you for your quick reply . is there any other way than using static keyword

Comment: Welcome @SannySinghs! Check the second example, It's not using `static` keyword, instead it's using `Scope`.

Answer (score 0):

someone answer me like this .

**add following in SessionsController**

```
$type = ...
$data = ...

$email = new Email;
$email->sendMail($type,$data);
```

Comment: Did you check my second example, without `static` keyword, it's possible using your approach but why not use `Laravel` style syntax, which is easy to use too, `Class::mentodName()` even it's not static.