# if condition for unique title name else create new in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i am using laravel i want to use if condition in my controller
if product title is already exist in my table so get product id
else create new title and get get product id 
Here is my table

```
 $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('image');
        $table->string('stock');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->string('gender');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                    ->onDelete('restrict')
                    ->onUpdate('restrict');
        $table->integer('designer_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('designer_id')->references('id')->on('designers')
                    ->onDelete('restrict')
                    ->onUpdate('restrict');
        $table->dateTime('published_at');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309033/find-or-create-with-eloquent).

[Laravel 5.x](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent) provides some methods such as `firstOrCreate` and `firstOrNew`

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem, please mark as solution. This can help others.

Comment: its look like right answer but i never did this so let me do first if its correct i will mark as sollution thanks

Comment: its working but how to save or need to save() class for save this

Comment: @SidHeart, please ask another question

Answer (score 0):

```
$validator = Validator::make(['title'=>$title], ['title' => 'string|unique:my_tbl']);
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return Response::json($validator->errors());
} else {
    $title = 'new Title';
    //Your Code
}
```