# How could I query (find) by the "name" attribute in Laravel/PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to follow this: [Find or Create with Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309033/find-or-create-with-eloquent)

and the findOrCreate public function would work perfectly, but even tho I have "getRouteKeyName()" right above the findOrCreate, using Tag::find() will look for the given data as an ID, not as the name.

Should I make a completely new and custom PHP file with a function called findOrCreate, or there's a way I can tell this function to look-up by name and not by id?

```php
public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'name';
    }
    public static function findOrCreate(array $tags){ <---- contains strings "default", "example", "other"
        return Tag::find($tags[0]); <---- this only accepts IDs, but $tags[0] points to "default", not an ID. Obviously, it should look up the database via the name.
    }
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: If you're manually defining this, then the equivalent would be `Tag::where('name', $tags[0])->first()`. `Tag::find($id)` is basically shorthand for `Tag::where('id', $id)->first()`.

Comment: I see, changing it from find to where worked out. now I have a different problem, eventho I have ```$fillable = ['name']``` , it throws me ```Add [name] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on``` when trying to call ```Tag::create(['name'=>$tag])``` I'm beginning to lose hope tbh

Comment: Hmm, that _should_ work; how did you define `$fillable` on `Tag.php`? Is it `protected $fillable = ['name'];`? Alternatively, you can define `protected $guarded = ['id'];` to allow all columns aside from `id` (which should be auto-incrementing anyway) to be "fillable" during `create()` and/or `update()` calls.

Comment: it is ```protected $fillable = ['name', 'slug'];```

Comment: Huh, again, that _should_ work. What does `dd((new Tag())->getFillable())` return? (You can run that in something like `php artisan tinker`, or anywhere in your code, etc.)

Comment: Forgive me but why wouldn't updateOrCreate serve the same purpose? you can specify the attributes to match against.

Comment: @TimLewis I had to have some sleep. I must've miss-spelled something because I re-wrote the entire Tag.php and now it works.

Comment: @futureweb I looked that up in the documentation and I'm surprised that it's only mentioned one time in the "eloquent" part. That did the job, thank both of you!

Comment: Lol, sometimes you need to do that  There are some cases where when you make a change to a file, like renaming a class, or fixing a casing issue in a class/filename (like `MyVIPModel` to `MyVipModel`, etc.) where that change doesn't propagate until you call `composer dump-autoload`, but this _shouldn't_ have been one of those cases. Glad you got it working though 